# How to change focus to the next EditText after reaching maxLength?

Tags: android

My app uses registration by phone number. So, I divided phone number inputs for some reasons. Also, I set maxLength for them. Let's imagine that there are two editText and the first one has limits to 2 units. After input of 2 units app should automatically send user(or change focus) to another EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in java:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if(editable.toString().length() == 2) {
                    editText2.requestFocus()
                }
            }
        });
```

in kotlin:

```
editText1.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
            if(count == 2) {
                editText2.requestFocus()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bro can you please tell me how to do it back. From edittext2 to edittext1? Main problem is to set the focus on the last character of edittext

Comment: you just have to set another TextWatcher to editText2 with the method addTextChangedListener and in the method afterTextChanged of this textWatcher do `editText1.requestFocus()` when editable.toString().lenght() == yourEditText2Size

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(edittext1.getText().toString().length()==size)     //size is your limit
        {
            edittext2.requestFocus();
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but another answer has more information, so I checked that one, sorry.

Comment: No problem @SardorAKayumov